# ListView with background image and custom cell colors

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, background, listviewitem

I have a listview that uses custom cell colors, but when I set a background image in the listview, the custom cell colors will not appear anymore. I tried to remove the background image temporarily (when assembling the list) and restore it after applying cell colors. This results in no custom colors but shows the background. I would like to combine these 2 listview properties if possible.

My code for setting/removing background image:

```
list.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.bgalpha;
list.BackgroundImage = null;
```

A part of my code for setting custom cell colors:

```
for (int i = 0; i < kavels.Count(); i++ )
{
    if (list.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text != "0")
    {
        list.Items[i].UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
        list.Items[i].SubItems[1].BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    }
}
```

Here are two screenshots:

List view with background: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o74e5.png

List view without background: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K21Ty.png

I also tried making a PictureBox with a transparent background along with a png image with transparency on top of the ListView, but that also didn't work obviously.

Comment: Color.LightGreen is opaque. Use Color.FromArgb(128, Color.LightGreen) etc.. instead!

Comment: Thanks, but the result is exactly the same.

Comment: You are right. All the colors are transformed to opaque. If you overlay the image it will make the LV non-clickable and also look a little bit diferent but otherwise should work __if the LV is parent of that panel or pb__..

Comment: Scrolling work fine now and I see a decent performance, too. Your mileage may very, though

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- You could overlay a `Panel` or a `PictureBox` with a semi-transprent Image. For this to work you would have to make it sit inside the ListView, so that it is the `Parent` of the overlay.

But that will make the `Listview` **non-clickable**. - Another problem with this is that it will slightly color the text, so it won't look quite right.

- Or you can set the `ListView` to `OwnerDraw = true` and add code to do the drawing yourself.

Here is an example, non-scrolled and scrolled:

[image][image]

Note that the original `BackgroundImage` shines through the emtpy space to the right.

If you owner-draw a ListView in Details mode you need to code events to draw subitems and headers; note the class level variable to hold the itemHeight; this assumes they all have the same Height .. The other one is need for horizontal scrolling.

```
int itemHeight = 0;  // we need this number!
int itemLeft = 0;    // we need this number, too

private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender,
                                        DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle R0 = listView1.GetItemRect(0);
    itemHeight = R0.Height;   // we need this number!
    itemLeft = R0.Left;       // we need this number too

    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawText();
}

private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender,
                                   DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle rrr = listView1.GetItemRect(e.ItemIndex);
    Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
    Rectangle rect0 = new Rectangle(rect.X - itemLeft , itemHeight * e.ItemIndex,
                                    rect.Width, rect.Height);
    Image img = listView1.BackgroundImage;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, rect, rect0, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(e.SubItem.BackColor))
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
    e.DrawText();
}
```

Here is the code to set the colors in the `ListViewItem lvi` for the example:

```
lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
lvi.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(66, Color.LightBlue);
lvi.SubItems[1].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(77, Color.LightGreen);
lvi.SubItems[2].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(88, Color.LightPink);
```

Note that the code assumes your background is **one** large image and **no tiling** is involved! Also the code works only if you don't have **groups**!

Answer (score 0):

[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/) -- an open source wrapper around a standard .NET `ListView` -- provides `ImageOverlays` and true background images too. They both work with colour cells.

[image: Translucent overlaid images]