# Using a transparent background image on datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I managed to build a darts scoring app programmed in C#(Winforms).
For scoring I used a Datagridview. Everything works quite nice so far, but for design purposes I'd like to use semitransparent Background Image, like I used for the Panels.

Unfortunately the Datagridview it self has no Background Image Property, so i wonder if its possible to customize Datagridview to achieve the following:
Background Image for The Control itself and transparent Background for Cells?

I would be happy if someone can help me because i don't understand how to customize the appearance  of Controls.

Thanks in advance.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Well, that is how DGV works. - [ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282743/listview-with-background-image-and-custom-cell-colors/30284799#30284799) example

Answer (score 0):

I have not done it, but it should be possible by creating a new control inheriting from the DataGridView as described in this post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/628f8b29-1192-4c67-bae9-91547dd37039/assign-background-image-to-datagridview?forum=winforms

But I think you should consider an alternative approach which is to use a 3PP control known as ObjectListView, which can support background images.

Details can be found here:
http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

This requires a different approach, but once you master it then it is very powerful and very useful.

Comment: Well, this is not a DGV but a ListView.

Comment: Not excactly what i'm looking for, but i will look over it, maybe it is usefull anyway. Thank you.